# Gravity of two side-by-side TextViews

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to have two TextViews side-by-side, and I want one to be touching the right-side of the screen and the other, the left-side. I don't want to define the widths using numbers because screens of different sizes would behave differently. So I'm trying to use layout_gravity, which is not working for some reason.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="rrr"
    android:textColor="@color/secondTextColor"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="sss"
    android:textColor="@color/secondTextColor" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Are the 2 textviews supposed to touch each other in between? Or 1 only touches the left, the other right and they don't touch in between? If they touch in between then `weight` is enough and you don't need `weightSum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create one `LinearLayout` for each `TextView` as follows :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="start">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="rrr"
        android:textColor="#f2f2"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="sss"
            android:textColor="#f3f3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the important thing is that in your first `LinearLayout` you put `android:gravity="start"` and in your second one `android:gravity="end"`, then it will work :)

Use `end` instead of `right` to ensure correct behavior in right-to-left locales.

> Why is "end" better than "right"?

Using `Gravity#LEFT` and `Gravity#RIGHT` can lead to problems when a layout is rendered in locales where text flows from `right` to `left`.
Use `Gravity#START` and `Gravity#END` instead. Similarly, in `XML` gravity and `layout_gravity` attributes, use `start` rather than `left`.
For XML attributes such as `paddingLeft` and `layout_marginLeft`, use `paddingStart` and `layout_marginStart`.
NOTE: If your `minSdkVersion` is less than 17, you should add both the older `left/right` attributes as well as the new `start/right` attributes. On older platforms, where `RTL` is not supported and the `start/right` attributes are unknown and therefore ignored, you need the older `left/right` attributes. There is a separate lint check which catches that type of error.

(Note: For `Gravity#LEFT` and `Gravity#START`, you can use these constants even when targeting older platforms, because the start bitmask is a superset of the left bitmask. Therefore, you can use `gravity="start"` rather than `gravity="left|start"`.)

Comment: Thanks! It worked without 2 more Linear Layouts though. Why is "end" better than "right"?

Comment: @JoãoMarcos the reason why is better, is basically to easily support RTL languages (Right to left) without changing your layouts, see: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Answer (score 3):

You can try with **`android:layout_weight`**  & **`android:gravity`**  .

Read **[What does android:layout_weight mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)** & **[Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)**

```
 <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="1" >

 <TextView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Intellij" />

 <TextView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="right" // You can add end instead of right
    android:text="Amiya" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `end` instead of `right` to ensure correct behavior in right-to-left locales, and the same goes for `left`

Comment: @Skizo Okay okay .Updated . Thanks .

Comment: I didn't know about the weightSum attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `android:layout_weight="1"` on `TextView's` and `0dp` for `width`.

Comment: Why do you consider that it is not elegant? Here is a tutorial with good explanations of how weights can be used in layout files: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMksRBvYG28)