# Different Gravity of two textviews in a horizontal Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gravity

I am using the following code and when I set gravity to the first textview to `center`, automatically the second textview's text is also getting aligned with the first one. Even Though I set the gravity of second view to `top`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

There was a solution in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038964/gravity-of-two-side-by-side-textviews) which says to wrap the 2nd textview in another LinearLayout. But why is it so?

Comment: Instead using 2 linearlayout, use relativelayout. just my 2cents.

Comment: LinearLayout means you can align views one by one (vertically/ horizontally).  In sequence manner the way you initializes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A horizontal `LinearLayout` aligns its child `View`s by their baselines by default, so the second `TextView` is being moved to align its text with the first's. To fix your problem, simply set the `LinearLayout`'s `baselineAligned` attribute to `false`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
```